# Table join without the first tables id?

Tags: sql, join

my question from the following query is how does the right join to the  dm_fiscal_cal table work?
I understand that you can join on fields that don't have a pk fk relationship but how does this ( on mom.approval_wes = fc.week_ending_sunday ) work when it isn't related to the job_order table?

```
SELECT 
    jo.order_id
    ,cd.client_id
    ,st.staff_name
    ,c.company_name
    ,ma.market_code
    ,SUM(mom.gross_profit)
FROM 
---- main table for order information
-- anchoring the query in this table means only clients with orders will return
    job_order as jo
LEFT JOIN 
--- main mart table for "aqent staff" coordinator id is the agent
    dm_staffhier_d as st
        on jo.coordinator_id = st.person_id   
---- secondary table for clients and their markets each order is related to a "client / market" combination. 
--- You must join on both to identify the correct market for the client where the order exists
LEFT JOIN
    client_default as cd    
        on jo.client_id = cd.client_id and 
        jo.market_id=cd.market_id  
--- primary table for clients
--- each client id is represented once and only once in this tbl
LEFT JOIN 
client as c
    on cd.client_id=c.client_id

--- market lookup table. there are market_ids that relate to many objects (orders, clients, people, leads, ..etc)
--- always make sure you're anchoring the market_id (Fk) on the correct object for the query results. You can (and often do) need
--  to alias this table for multiple uses
LEFT JOIN
    market as ma
        on jo.market_id= ma.market_id   

---- main finanacial data mart tbl. each order fee for each week, for each client is represented.
--- you can join on order id for this query. You could use otherer relations ships for other queries
LEFT JOIN
    dm_mainordermetrics_f as mom
        on jo.order_id=mom.order_id

--- fiscal calendar tbl
--- we're joining this to the financial tbl because we're looking for GP$ in a certain period. That period is 
--- easily found by using the dm_fiscal_cal tbl (fiscal year 2017).
RIGHT JOIN
    dm_fiscal_cal as fc
        on mom.approval_wes = fc.week_ending_sunday
WHERE 
--- market requirement for LA, and BOS
    ma.short_description IN ('Los Angeles', 'Boston')
--- not a good solution for this - check having clause 
--    AND mom.gross_profit >0
    AND  fc.fiscal_year = 2017
GROUP BY 
     jo.order_id
    ,st.staff_name
    ,cd.client_id
    ,c.company_name
    ,ma.market_code

having sum(mom.gross_profit) > 0

order by 4,1
--- you should get 1509 rows
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You are misusing `GROUP BY`. Please read [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html). Your query is likely to yield unpredictable results, if it works at all.

Comment: Learn how to ask question here.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

So it seems like your new to StackOverflow and SQL. First, I'll try and answer your original question.

My interpretation is that you are asking if the second `LEFT JOIN` (which is also sometimes referred to as a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`) is a valid statement in SQL even though it does not contain either the `job.order_id` nor the `fiscal.cal_id`.

The answer to this question is **yes** the statement is a valid one and it will run. That does not mean it will necessarily return any records or that it is doing exactly what you want it to be doing.

I apologize if that was not your intended question, but this brings me to my second point.

You should edit your original question to be more clear about what you want to know. If you did any research on your own before asking it, provide links to the sites you were looking through. Add the relevant columns on the tables in the `FROM` clause of your query. Lastly, think carefully about what specifically it is that you don't understand. Perhaps highlight those line(s) of code in your question.

All of this will help us to better answer your question.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I found my question answered in another post. That answer was "A primary key is not required. A foreign key is not required either. You can construct a query joining two tables on any column you wish as long as the datatypes either match or are converted to match. No relationship needs to explicitly exist."

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution. :) Do try to keep in mind what I said about asking questions in the future though.